Missing render device for AMD GPU under Ubuntu 24.04
I am running Ubuntu 24.04 in a VM under TrueNAS Scale.
My Ryzen 4650Gs iGPU gets passed through to the VM.
I would like to use the GPU to accelerate transcodes in a Jellyfin docker container.
I do have a card1 device under /dev/dri but no renderD128.
I have tried passing the HD Audio device as well as the Multimedia Controller device in addition to just the GPU. That did not change anything.
Installing the AMDGPU driver from the installer under https://repo.radeon.com/amdgpu-install/6.2/ubuntu/noble/ also didn't change anything.
Any ideas how to get this working?
I also found this in syslog:
2024-08-08T00:21:12.453464+02:00 mediastack kernel: [drm] initializing kernel modesetting (RENOIR 0x1002:0x1636 0x1458:0x1000 0xD9).
2024-08-08T00:21:12.453464+02:00 mediastack kernel: [drm] register mmio base: 0xFC000000
2024-08-08T00:21:12.453464+02:00 mediastack kernel: [drm] register mmio size: 524288
2024-08-08T00:21:12.453464+02:00 mediastack kernel: [drm] add ip block number 0 <soc15_common>
2024-08-08T00:21:12.453468+02:00 mediastack kernel: [drm] add ip block number 1 <gmc_v9_0>
2024-08-08T00:21:12.453468+02:00 mediastack kernel: [drm] add ip block number 2 <vega10_ih>
2024-08-08T00:21:12.453469+02:00 mediastack kernel: [drm] add ip block number 3 <psp>
2024-08-08T00:21:12.453469+02:00 mediastack kernel: [drm] add ip block number 4 <smu>
2024-08-08T00:21:12.453469+02:00 mediastack kernel: [drm] add ip block number 5 <dm>
2024-08-08T00:21:12.453470+02:00 mediastack kernel: [drm] add ip block number 6 <gfx_v9_0>
2024-08-08T00:21:12.453473+02:00 mediastack kernel: [drm] add ip block number 7 <sdma_v4_0>
2024-08-08T00:21:12.453474+02:00 mediastack kernel: [drm] add ip block number 8 <vcn_v2_0>
2024-08-08T00:21:12.453474+02:00 mediastack kernel: [drm] add ip block number 9 <jpeg_v2_0>
2024-08-08T00:21:12.453474+02:00 mediastack kernel: [drm] BIOS signature incorrect 0 0
2024-08-08T00:21:12.453475+02:00 mediastack kernel: [drm] BIOS header is broken
2024-08-08T00:21:12.453475+02:00 mediastack kernel: [drm] BIOS signature incorrect 0 0
2024-08-08T00:21:12.453475+02:00 mediastack kernel: amdgpu 0000:00:07.0: amdgpu: Unable to locate a BIOS ROM
2024-08-08T00:21:12.453479+02:00 mediastack kernel: amdgpu 0000:00:07.0: amdgpu: Fatal error during GPU init
2024-08-08T00:21:12.453479+02:00 mediastack kernel: amdgpu 0000:00:07.0: amdgpu: amdgpu: finishing device.


Do you expect an accelerated graphics under VM, are you sure?
